# Why can't you cast a constrained open generic typed to the constrained type?

Tags: c#, generics

I think I must be missing something, why can't I compile this:

```
class Foo<T> where T : Bar
{
    T Bar;
}

abstract class Bar
{ }

class MyBar : Bar
{ }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fooMyBar = new Foo<MyBar>();
    AddMoreFoos(fooMyBar);
}

static void AddMoreFoos<T>(Foo<T> FooToAdd) where T : Bar
{
    var listOfFoos = new List<Foo<Bar>>();
    listOfFoos.Add(FooToAdd); //Doesn't compile
    listOfFoos.Add((Foo<Bar>)FooToAdd); //doesn't compile
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're make things a little bit more confusing than they need to be by using a list here... it's easiest to see the effect this way:

```
// This won't compile
Foo<Bar> fooBar = new Foo<MyBar>();
```

Given that this doesn't compile, it's then not surprising that you can't add a `Foo<MyBar>` to a `List<Foo<Bar>>`

So why isn't a `Foo<MyBar>` a `Foo<Bar>`? Because generic classes aren't covariant.

Generic variance was only introduced in C# 4 - and it only works for interfaces and delegates. So you could (in C# 4) do:

```
IEnumerable<MyBar> x = new List<MyBar>();
IEnumerable<Bar> y = x;
```

but you couldn't do:

```
IList<MyBar> x = new List<MyBar>();
IList<Bar> y = x;
```

I have a whole talk about variance which you can download from the [NDC 2010 video site](http://streaming.ndc2010.no) - just search for "variance".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because if you were to call your method with a `Foo<int>` then the call will fail: you are trying to assume a specific type for your generic parameter.

What you need is to use `var listOfFoos = new List<Foo<T>>()` instead, then the `Add` should work.

(EDIT: equally, the cast would work if you used `Foo<T>` - but you still can't assume in your code that `T` is `Bar`).

Comment: 'if you were to call your method with a Foo<int> then the call will fail' => but this call would not compile because of the generic constraint, where T : Bar, no?  However, +1 for new List<Foo<T>>() as this actually solves my real problem!

Comment: Good point on the constraint.  Confused as to why you accepted the other answer if I solved your problem tho... (Jon Skeet or not! ;-))